# pyserial response unicodeDecodeError

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial

```
import serial
s = serial.Serial(port = 'Com3', 9600, timeout = 2) 
data = s.readline().decode().rstrip("\r\n")
```

So basically when I try to read the data I get the error.

**UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfb in position 20: invalid start byte**

From the documentation of the instrument I am trying to communicate with. the **data** is in the form:
**..ss3422/34/54--1.8E+03<,>…..0.7E+03<,...1.71E-09<,<√.<*.<**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem by changing to encoding = "ISO-8859-1".

Comment: This also worked for me when trying to migrate Python 2 code over to 3 using the pyserial module.